# Работа с файлами javascript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо получить список файлов в папке и открыть их, используя js? Каким образом это можно сделать? Нашел способ через ActiveXObject, но он не работал на всех браузерах, кроме IE...

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript не имеет доступа к файловой системе. Поэтому получить список файлов и открыть их, используя только JavaScript нельзя. Можно

1. использовать FileAPI из HTML 5,
2. использовать возможности ActiveX в IE,
3. использовать возможности NPAPI в Firefox, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: 4\. использовать апплеты.